# Update Wpf Image after FileSystemWatcher Event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I am trying to load an image onto my WPF Window after it is received through a FileSystemEvent, however, I cannot access the image slot on the window because the FileSystemEvent happens on a different thread. I have read to use dispatchers and invoking, but nothing I try fixes the problem. Here is my code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = directory;
        watcher.Filter = "*.jpg";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        BitmapImage b=new BitmapImage();
        b.BeginInit();
        b.UriSource=new Uri(e.FullPath);
        b.EndInit();
        image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => image1.Source = b); //What goes here?
        //I have also tried Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke
    }
```

And

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `b.Freeze()` (on the thread that created it) to make it available to other threads.